# MS-Excel - Macro to copy unique cells from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to writing macros in VBA.

I am working on automating a process.

This is what I need to do

**Sample Data**
*Sheet1*

```
Group_Name
  RootGrp1
  RootGrp2
  RootGrp3
```

*Sheet2*

```
Group_Name - Member_Name
  RootGrp1 - Member_A
  RootGrp1 - Member_B
  RootGrp1 - Member_C
  RootGrp2 - Member_D
  RootGrp2 - Member_B
  RootGrp2 - Member_C
  RootGrp3 - Member_A
  RootGrp3 - Member_B
  RootGrp3 - Member_E
  Member_A - Member_F
```

**Result**
*Sheet1-Modified*

```
Group_Name
  RootGrp1
  RootGrp2
  RootGrp3
  Member_A
  Member_B
  Member_C
  Member_D
  Member_E
  Member_F
```

**Process**

1. It parses through Sheet1.
2. For every entry present, it adds all corresponding Member_Names from Sheet2 to Sheet1. (Taking care to ignore any Member_Name which has already been added)
3. Repeat till all entries in Sheet1 are processed. (Including the ones added dynamically)

*Is there any way to do this? Please help!!!*

Below is the code that I have come up with till now. Facing some problems with the FindNext method currently.

```
Sub My_Function()


    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Set Marker = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column)


    Do Until IsEmpty(Marker)

        Query = Marker.Value
        With Sheets(2).Range("A1", "A20")
            Set Index = .Find(Query, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not Index Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = Index.Address

                Do
                    Result = Index.Offset(0, 1)

                    With Sheets(1).Range("A1", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
                        Set Lookup = .Find(Result, LookIn:=xlValues)
                        If Lookup Is Nothing Then
                            Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Result
                        End If
                    End With

                    Set Index = .FindNext(Index)
                Loop While Not Index Is Nothing And Index.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With

        Set Marker = Marker.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop

End Sub
```

P.S - I know the code isn't very well written. Please excuse, as this is my first proper VBA Macro.

Comment: +1 for a well written question. The simple answer is "Yes, it can be done".  Have you already tried to write a macro to do this? If so, edit your question to include what you have done so far; you will get the most help if you have attempted to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: I agree with Rachel. If you don't know where to start, you can have a look at the [Excel Macro Recorder](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/record-modify-run-excel-macro.php)

Comment: I've uploaded the code till now. Stuck with the nested Find and FindNext Method.

Comment: Found it. Used .Find method instead of FindNext....

Comment: +1 Great work on producing such a well written and formatted question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out. Tweaked your code a bit.

```
Sub fMain()
    Sheets(1).Activate
    Range("A2").Select
    Set Marker = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, ActiveCell.Column)
    Do Until IsEmpty(Marker)
        Query = Marker.Value
        With Sheets(2).Range("A2", "A20")
            Set Index = .Find(Query, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not Index Is Nothing Then
                firstAddress = Index.Address
                Do
                    Result = Index.Offset(0, 1)
                    fHelper Result
                    Set Index = .Find(What:=Query, After:=Index)
                Loop While Not Index Is Nothing And Index.Address <> firstAddress
            End If
        End With
        Set Marker = Marker.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub

Sub fHelper(Result)
    With Sheets(1).Range("A2", Range("A65536").End(xlUp))
        Set Lookup = .Find(Result, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Lookup Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Result
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```